# Combining multiple meshes in one animated model into one mesh, libgdx

Tags: model, 3d, libgdx, mesh

I got some animated character models (which I did not create myself) I have looked at them in Maya and they consist of 5-7 separate meshes; body, eyes, cloak, sword etc. Each model rendered in libgdx adds about 35 draw calls... I want to reduce this. I was thinking that I should combine all the meshes of the model into one. I could not do this in Maya (well, it worked using the combine mesh feature, it still animated fine etc but I could not export it to FBX after the mesh combine so I can not get them into my game). So I was thinking maybe there is a way to do this in code instead?

Is there any way that I can merge/combine all the meshes in those models with lbgdx code? I have looked at MeshPartBuilder.addMesh() but from what I understand it will not merge the meshes I add into one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MeshPartBuilder.addMesh` can be used to merge (parts of) meshes. But assuming you're talking about skinning, then it won't work like that because the bone information will be different. You'd have to manually update the bone index of each vertex. You're better off combining them in a modeling application.

Besides merging the mesh in your modeling application, there are also others aspects to consider. For example, the mesh should not be more than 32k vertices in size (the maximum value of java `short`, which is used for the indices), otherwise fbx-conv will split it into smaller parts.

Likewise, fbx-conv will split the mesh if it is actively influenced by more than 12 bones. You can change this using the `-b` commandline option. See: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/3D-animations-and-skinning#loading-skinning

Comment: Thank you for this info. Do you also think that ~35 draw calls for 1 animated model is a lot? As I said the models got several meshes and also pretty complex HIK skeletons which amounts to pretty large fbx files when I include animation. Is there anything I can do from code to optimize animated 3d-models? Considering that I know the the amount of draw calls is a bottleneck for me

Comment: never mind I got the link to work by copy pasting (http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=12910&p=57297#p57250. goes to the main wiki page when you click it)

Comment: Good catch! Should be fixed now.